# Unhandled exception 'java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create native thread: possibly out of memory or process/resource limits reached

Tags: java, spring-boot, out-of-memory, openshift, forkjoinpool

We have recently migrated a springboot application to **2.7.11** version, and while performing a load test, a nasty error raised :

> "Unhandled exception 'java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create native thread: possibly out of memory or process/resource limits reached

we noticed that the app now consumes a bit more memory than lhe last version, so i tried to collect some profiling infos through visualvm, and i noticed that a forkjoinpool (a custom thread pool with parallelism is set to 5) is creating many thread than expected (300 thread instead of 5):
[image]

Roughly speaking, the app parse a big json file and cuts it into several pieces, and foreach part we send a task to the forkjoinpool through executor.execute().

Noting that we are serving this application on openshift V4, and we've never got this weird error when using springboot **2.6.6**.

Comment: You haven't asked a question.

Comment: maybe its not clear, i wanted to ask if there is an issue with the version 2.7.11 of springboot. In fact, under the same circumstances and conditions, we never had this error with the version 2.6.6 .

Comment: Maybe it just consumes more memory? Check your memory usage before and after, maybe you were very close to the limit before? If you get any memory metrics (before and after), please add them to your question.

Comment: The ForkJoinPool is creating over 300 Threads and you only require 5 parallel threads. How did the previous version behave in that specific area? As others point out it may be that you were close to failure before but it may also be the case that settings on the VM or in the libraries have upped to requirements.

Comment: The forkjoinpool is  also creating  more threads than expected in the previous version, i have no idea about the root cause of that behavior.

Comment: @user2676594 That sounds like where to look. The default Stack Size for a Thread is typically 512K so 300 will be soaking up over 150 MiB. The default constructor for `java.util.concurrent.ForJoinPool` creates a pool with the same number of threads as `Runtime.AvailableProcessors()`. But it sounds like the Application Code should be trying to set it...

Answer (score 1):

If your tasks take a long time to execute, there's a risk that ForkJoinPool could create additional threads to maintain a degree of parallelism.

Answer (score 1):

Just because you have 300 threads in the ThreadGroup named "ForkJoinPool", it doesn't mean all of those threads were created by the ForkJoinPool. If the runnable tasks themselves create separate (sub-) threads, those threads will also be in the same thread group. Given that your ForkJoinPool has a parallelism of only 5, it is the most likely case that your threads are themselves creating other threads. Check the code of the threads created by your ForkJoinPool.